# How to enable Kotlins "unit conversions on arbitrary expressions"

Tags: kotlin

I'm getting a Kotlin Error:

> The feature "unit conversions on arbitrary expressions" is
> experimental and should be enabled explicitly. You can also change the
> original type of this expression to (...) -> Unit

My code is the following:

```
val foo: () -> String = { "Test" }

fun bar(doSometing: () -> Unit) { /* */ }

val baz = bar(foo) // here foo throws the error
```

It's pretty obvious what i'm doing wrong: `bar` expects `() -> Unit`, but i provide `() -> String`.

However, the error message implies i can opt in to "unit conversions on arbitrary expressions". How do i do this?

The only thing related i could find here on SO doesn't answer my question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238339/kotlin-the-feature-unit-conversion-is-disabled`

Comment: What version of Kotlin is this?

Comment: Kotlin version is "1.7.10" as far as i can tell

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you can get around this problem using `val baz = bar { foo() }`. If you want to research it further, the source of the message is [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/cdbfcdc4650c8c7953db1c723300daa6a299c0c4/compiler/frontend.common-psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/LanguageFeatureMessageRenderer.kt#L29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting that you can pass a function reference but not an equivalent expression:

```
fun f(): String = "Test"
val foo = ::f
fun bar(doSometing: () -> Unit) { /* */ }

val baz = bar(::f)  // OK
val baz2 = bar(foo) // Error
```

You can make it compile using the command-line option
`-XXLanguage:+UnitConversionsOnArbitraryExpressions` but it's not recommended:

```
$ cat t.kt
val foo: () -> String = { "Test" }

fun bar(doSometing: () -> Unit) { /* */ }

val baz = bar(foo)

$ kotlinc t.kt
t.kt:5:15: error: the feature "unit conversions on arbitrary expressions" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly. You can also change the original type of this expression to (...) -> Unit
val baz = bar(foo)
              ^
$ kotlinc -XXLanguage:+UnitConversionsOnArbitraryExpressions t.kt 
warning: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:

-XXLanguage:+UnitConversionsOnArbitraryExpressions

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!

t.kt:3:9: warning: parameter 'doSometing' is never used
fun bar(doSometing: () -> Unit) { /* */ }
        ^
$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the expected type of doSometing is () -> Unit, but given () -> String, you can fix it by modify return type of foo or modify type of doSometing

both

```
val foo: () -> Unit = { println("Test") }

fun bar(doSometing: () -> Unit) { doSometing() }

val baz = bar(foo)
```

.

```
val foo: () -> String = { "Test" }

fun bar(doSometing: () -> String) { /* */ }

val baz = bar(foo)
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue if I just did this it didn't work

```
val foo = { uiEvent: ScreenUiEvent ->
  when (uiEvent) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Adding the type I didn't get any error

```
val foo: (ScreenUiEvent) -> Unit = { uiEvent ->
  when (uiEvent) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Comment: Dows the following help: in the first example, add a "unit" before the last closing bracket?